# When editing a question, please don't reset the tags field if input validation fails

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits

Steps to repro:

1. Edit a question
2. Modify the tags field (should still be valid)
3. Modify the title so it's invalid (either blank or 1 char)
4. Click submit

Expected result:

- Error message saying that the title is invalid
- Tags field retains the edits made from above

Actual result:

- Error message saying that the title is invalid
- Tags field is *reverted* to what it was originally when editing began
- <sup><sub>Jon is very annoyed</sub></sup>

I get this most often on old questions where short titles were allowed, but I just got it now on a question where the title is too long for the [new validation rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45046/length-limit-for-question-titles-that-have-nothing-to-do-with-unicorns-we-dont/48237#48237).

---

Note: there is also some of this kind of behaviour with the title field, but it works fine (if you erase the whole field, it gets rolled back to what it was before; but if you don't erase all of it, it keeps the edit, although it doesn't submit).

Comment: +1, I too encountered this once or twice, but didn't mind posting a bugreport.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, thanks. That should work the next time we deploy.