# Title error loses tags

Tags: bug, edits, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When editing a question, please don't reset the tags field if input validation fails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50025/when-editing-a-question-please-dont-reset-the-tags-field-if-input-validation-fa)

When attempting to re-tag a question, if the title validation throws an error (such as if the title is too short) then the edit page on which the error is displayed reverts to the *original* tags, losing the editor's work. The editor must fix the problem *and* re-do the retagging.

Comment: Yep, dupe. That one didn't come up in the list of similar questions when I was submitting.