# Title length should be checked while asking the question also

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, title

I recently tried to a make a edit to a post, I made changes to the body of the post and kept the title as it is. I got the following message and then I had to edit the title to place the edit.

[image: Title too long]

So, this validation should be placed at the time of asking the question. What do you say ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is simply an old question; the restriction on title length was put in place in [May 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45046/length-limit-for-question-titles-that-have-nothing-to-do-with-unicorns-we-dont) and the question is older than this change. The Title column in the Posts table is a nvarchar(250).

There are only [325 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/96628/posts-with-a-title-of-length-150) with titles longer than 150 characters; so, I don't see this as a major problem.

The "proper" solution would be to change all of these questions to have a title length of 150 or less characters and alter the column or add a constraint. I'm not sure it's worth the bother; it depends whether all the checks are done in code, or not.

Interestingly, the [newer Stack Exchange sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel%20answers/query/new) have a maximum size of nvarchar(250) as well; a just in case thing?